# DataFrame Extract int/number values from string?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I have a df with values in a column.
`df` :

```
        a    
0    abc_test_0120_12346
1    def_abc def_0420_9658
```

I want to take out only int/numbers.
Excepted Output is `df` :

```
        a    
0    012012346
1    04209658
```

Comment: I have tried this `df.a.str.extract('(^\d*)')`

Comment: "What about "abc_123 def_456"? Is the answer "123456" or "123 456" with the space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is replace non numbers to emty strings:

```
df['a'] = df.a.str.replace('\D+', '')
print (df)
           a
0  012012346
1   04209658
```